# Property of Kernel in additive category

Tags: category-theory

I am in the beginning of Category Theory.

This is the definition of kernel of a morphism in an additive category that i'm using:

"In an additive category the kernel of a morphism $\phi: A \rightarrow B$ is an object $\operatorname{ker}(\phi)$ together with a morphism $\kappa: \operatorname{ker}(\phi) \rightarrow A$ such that every morphism $\psi: C \rightarrow A$ with $\phi \circ \psi=0$ factors uniquely as a composite $C \rightarrow \operatorname{ker}(\phi) \stackrel{\kappa}{\rightarrow} A$."

Is it true that $\phi \circ \kappa=0$? I think it should follow directly from the definition, but i can't prove it. Can you help me?

Comment: I thought that was usually built in to the definition of kernel.  What if you apply the universal part of the definition to $C=0$, $\psi =0$?

Comment: Every reference on my desk makes $\phi \circ \kappa =0$ a part of the definition itself.

Comment: Please do not use images to convey critical information not otherwise present in your post. [Here is the explanation why](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I fixed it

Comment: @Randall thank you, can you give me the references that you are using?

Comment: Weibel, Hilton-Stammbach, Eilenberg, etc.

Comment: @Randall I don't believe that works, the $C=0$ thing. This only tells you that $\kappa\circ(0)=0$ which is obvious.

Comment: @FShrike yes, but I was wondering if the requirement of *unique* factorization might force more.

Comment: To the op: the correct statement includes $\phi\circ\kappa=0$. Equivalently, we say a map to $A$ has $\phi\psi=0$ **if and only if** $\psi$ factors through $\kappa$, in which case the factorisation is unique. In particular, using the "if" clause, $\psi:=\kappa\circ1=\kappa$ has $\phi\circ\psi=\phi\circ\kappa=0$. Thinking a bit more abstractly, what you really want is for  $\kappa_\ast:\hom(-,\ker\phi)\to\hom(-,A)$ to be the usual kernel, in the sense of Abelian groups, of $\phi_\ast:\hom(-,A)\to\hom(-,B)$